# Change color depth in KDE?

Tags: kde, wine, color-depth

So I was running a game trough wine and it changed my resolution and color depth. Was easy to get the resolution back to normal but can't find any way to change the color depth back. How do I do it without restating X? I mean, if there is a way to change it to a lower value like wine did there must be an easy way to change it back, right?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change Xorg's colour depth on the fly due to its design - it must be restarted.

It essentially depends on your hardware since KDE uses SVG but there is a workaround which *might* work. Create a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` called `default.conf` containing:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen 1"
    DefaultDepth 16
EndSection
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to edit the xorg.conf and all that. This does not make sense to me though, if wine can change the color depth of X then why can't any other program do the same?

Comment: Gnome provides a GUI tool to do this too. As far as I know, wine runs on the same colour depth as Linux. However, colour depth is also a per-session kind of thing.

Comment: Normally yes, it was an old windows game that decided to change it. And it only changed it on the screen it was running on, I have a dual screen setup and the other screen was not affected bt the change. Do you know what the gnome tool is called? I have gtk installed anyway so could just as easily install a gnome program as a kde one.

Comment: I think it was kcontrol but that's just a guess. But I can only imagine that kcontrol changes the configuration of the Xorg file and you have to restart your system. Try giving it a go, maybe it'll work. Latest KDE versions don't support kcontrol, instead they have system-settings.